# Convert unicode String to Dictionary in python

Tags: python

I have a variable which holds the table name and columns as a string.
Below is the sample:

```
[(u'USER_SSO_PROPERTIES', u'[\n  "FULL_NAME",\n  "NAME"\n]'), (u'USERS', u'[\n  "EMAIL",\n  "NAME"\n]'), (u'PITCH_RECIPIENTS', u'[\n  "EMAIL",\n  "ID"\n]'), (u'USER_CLOUD_SERVICES', u'[\n  "EMAIL"\n]')]
```

I am trying to convert into a dictionary in python as below.

```
{'USER_SSO_PROPERTIES': ['FULL_NAME','NAME'],
 'PITCH_RECIPIENTS':['USER_CLOUD_SERVICES','EMAIL']}
```

How can I remove the \n and u and also convert it into the above format.
I searched on SO and those solutions did not work for me.

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Comment: I am using python 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `ast.literal_eval` and list-comprehension to achieve that:

```
import ast

t = [(u'USER_SSO_PROPERTIES', u'[\n  "FULL_NAME",\n  "NAME"\n]'), (u'USERS', u'[\n  "EMAIL",\n  "NAME"\n]'),
     (u'PITCH_RECIPIENTS', u'[\n  "EMAIL",\n  "ID"\n]'), (u'USER_CLOUD_SERVICES', u'[\n  "EMAIL"\n]')]
result = {k: ast.literal_eval(v) for k, v in t}
# {'USER_SSO_PROPERTIES': ['FULL_NAME', 'NAME'], 'USERS': ['EMAIL', 'NAME'], 'PITCH_RECIPIENTS': ['EMAIL', 'ID'], 'USER_CLOUD_SERVICES': ['EMAIL']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `eval()` to quickly convert literals to actual Python values.

This code can convert your example.

```
string = r'''[(u'USER_SSO_PROPERTIES', u'[\n  "FULL_NAME",\n  "NAME"\n]'), (u'USERS', u'[\n  "EMAIL",\n  "NAME"\n]'), (u'PITCH_RECIPIENTS', u'[\n  "EMAIL",\n  "ID"\n]'), (u'USER_CLOUD_SERVICES', u'[\n  "EMAIL"\n]')]'''

result_dict = {}
for table_name, columns_string in eval(string):
    result_dict[table_name] = eval(columns_string)

print(result_dict)
```

Try to run this code with other strings here.

https://www.pythonpad.co/pads/ri8adgokb5our8v1/

Answer (score 0):

Simple 1 liner using `eval`:

```
my_data = {k:eval(v) for k,v in text}
```